# How to pass data after ajax call response to another php page to submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass the result that I got from the ajax response to another page to submit a form with it.
I'm a PHP developer and I'm new to ajax and jquery. Your help will be really appreciated!!

plant.js page
...

```
                            function showPlant()
                            {
                               var x = document.getElementById('plant').value;
                               
                               $.ajax({
                                   url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?> Gencos/showPlant",
                                   method: "POST",
                                   data:{
                                       id : x
                                   },
                                   success:function(data){
                                       $("#ans").html(data);
                                   }
                                   
                               })
                            }
```

...

showplant.php
...

```
           if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
               
            $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']; //trying sessions
            
            $k = $_POST['id'];
            
            $k = trim($k);
            
           $query = "SELECT * FROM plants WHERE plant_name='{$k}'";
           
           $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
           
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
           {
             
               ?>
        
                        <label class="form-label">Owner</label>
                        <select name="owner" class="form-control select">
                            <option value="<?= $row['plant_owner'] ; ?>" selected disabled><?= $row['plant_owner'] ; ?></option>
                        </select>

                
                        <label class="form-label">Fuel</label>
                        <select name="fuel" class="form-control select">
                             <option value="<?= $row['plant_fuel'] ; ?>" selected disabled><?= $row['plant_fuel'] ; ?></option> 
                        </select>

                        <label class="form-label">Type</label>
                        <select name="type" class="form-control select">
                            <option value="<?= $row['plant_type'] ; ?>" selected disabled><?= $row['plant_type'] ; ?></option>
                        </select>

                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    
            
               
                                            <?php
           }
        }
```

?>

...

myform.php
...

```
`<label class="form-label">Plant</label>
                                            <select name="plant" id="plant" class="form-control select" onchange="showPlant()">
                                                <option disabled selected>Select Plant</option>   
                                            </select>

                                            <label class="form-label">Capacity</label>
                                           
                                                <input data-parsley-type="number" type="text" class="form-control" name="capacity" required placeholder="Enter only numbers" />
                                  
                                    <label>Date</label>
                                    <div class="input-group" id="datepicker2">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Y-M-D" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date-container='#datepicker2' data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true">
                       
                                <div id="ans" class="row">
                                 <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label class="form-label">Owner</label>
                                            <select class="form-control select">
                                                 <option value="" selected disabled>Owner</option>
                                                
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label class="form-label">Fuel</label>
                                            <select class="form-control select">
                                                <option selected disabled>Fuel</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                            <label class="form-label">Type</label>
                                            <select class="form-control select">
                                                <option selected disabled>Type</option>
                                            </select>

                                            </div>
                                        
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                 <div style="padding-top: 15px">
                                 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Data</button>
                                </div>
                                    
                            </form>
```

...

I want to submit a form after I get data from ajax response as you can see in plant.js the function showPlant is called after I select plant in myform.php it then shows values from the database based on the id of the select option.

Basically I want to submit the values from the ajax call as well as the values from myform.php all together in one form.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you want to do, cuz I see a lot of duplicate functionalities in your code, I guess what you want is simpler than what you have implemented.

Comment: Basically, i have a select field with an onchange function to show fields from the database , I used ajax to do that and I want to pass the value that is collected from the ajax response to myform.php to submit.